# Asp.net Identity 2.0 - Unique Email

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-identity

My application is MVC5, I tried to allow duplicate email address using the following:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> AddUser (UserRegisterViewModel userViewModel)
        {
       ......
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                var user = new ApplicationUser
                {
               ......
                };
                var adminresult = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user);
                var result = await UserManager.AddToRolesAsync(user.Id, user.Profession);
                UserManager.UserValidator = new UserValidator<ApplicationUser>(UserManager)
                {
                    RequireUniqueEmail = false
                };
                if (adminresult.Succeeded)
                    {
                     ....
                    return RedirectToAction("VisitInfo", "Visit");
                    }
                if (!adminresult.Succeeded)
                    {
                    var er = adminresult.Errors.FirstOrDefault();
                    ViewBag.Error = er;
                    return View(userViewModel);
                    }

                    return RedirectToAction("VisitInfo", "Visit");
                }               
            return View();
            }
```

By adding  RequireUniqueEmail = false. It did not work, the page is redirected to login page!!
My question is could I allow duplicate emails just for this action, and why I get redirected to login page?

Comment: Is that code all within the `AddUser` method?  If so, you are setting up the `UserValidator` AFTER creating the user.  It needs to go in `IdentityConfig.cs`

Comment: Thank you Brendan.  I could do that, however I need this rule to be in place for other registration forms.

Comment: If it is put in the `IdentityConfig.cs` then it will apply site wide.  As it stands, you're setting the `RequireUniqueEmail` flag after you've already created the user.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

If you are using the default MVC 5 project template, **the proper way is to set the rules in `IdentityConfig.cs`** instead of in the registration controller.

Open `App_Start\IdentityConfig.cs` and edit this line:

```
public static ApplicationUserManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationUserManager> options, IOwinContext context) 
{
    var manager = new ApplicationUserManager(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context.Get<ApplicationDbContext>()));
    // Configure validation logic for usernames
    manager.UserValidator = new UserValidator<ApplicationUser>(manager)
    {
        AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false,
        RequireUniqueEmail = false  //<-- the default is true
    };

    ....<snip>....
```

Comment: In Identity Core the default seems to be **false**

Answer (score 11):

you have to add below lines in configureservices

```
 services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(options =>
            {
                options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = false;

            })
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

Comment: Still when running migration it creates the ```UserNameIndex``` which has unique property set to true

Answer (score 7):

Thanks to Brendan, I moved

```
            UserManager.UserValidator = new UserValidator<ApplicationUser>(UserManager)
                {
                    RequireUniqueEmail = false
                };
```

Before:

```
 var adminresult = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user);
```

Comment: I was able to have two users with same phone even with `RequireUniquePhone = true` set.

Answer (score 0):

For `.NET Core` and `.NET5`+ it needs to be added as an option to the `IServiceCollection`

```
services.AddIdentityCore<AppUser>(opt =>
{
    opt.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
})
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<DataContext>();
```