# ASP.NET OWIN use Email to Login (instead of username)

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, owin

Currently, my application does OWIN authentication the following way (using **UserName** & **Password**, as in code below). I need to make users log in using their **email** (instead of username) and **password**.

As a workaround, I can find userName by email (entered by user) and then use current method (username + password), but this is a double database call, which I'm trying to avoid. Please advise. Thanks!

```
protected void LogIn(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (IsValid)
            {   
                var manager = new myUserManager(new myUserStore(new myDbContext()));

                myUser user = manager.Find(UserName.Text, Password.Text);

                if (user != null)
                {
                    IdentityHelper.SignIn(manager, user, RememberMe.Checked);
                    IdentityHelper.RedirectToReturnUrl(Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"], Response);
                }
                else
                {
                    FailureText.Text = "Invalid login";
                    ErrorMessage.Visible = true;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Configure AspNet Identity to require email addresses to be unique.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27515561/asp-net-identity-2-0-unique-email